# neo4j/Cypher toString() collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a simple graph model for hospitals. I am playing around with hiearchical trees in neo4j, so I created a multilevel location tree in graph.

[image]

Now I want to get GPS using apoc.spatial functions. Lets say that first 3 levels of locations are good enough for retrieving latitude and longitude. My query looks like this.

```
MATCH (h:Hospital)-[:IS_IN*..3]->(location)
CALL apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce(toString(collect(location.name))) YIELD location
set h += location
```

But this returns error since it does not support toString collections i guess.

> Expected a String, Number or Boolean, got: Vector(550 OSBORNE ROAD,
>   55432, FRIDLEY)

What is the simplest way to achieve this to work ?

Comment: How did you manage to customise the Hospital, Ownership & Rating nodes?

Comment: Neo4j Browser settings --> enable experimental features

Comment: The settings enable something or some features. How/what changes did you then define + display the custom node icon e.g. what changes to the grass file..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
RETURN substring(reduce(s="", name in collect(location.name) | s + "," + name),1)
```

Comment: The graphic from Tomaz also showed custom icons for Hospital, Ownership and Rating which is why I thought this was some additional wizardry...